# Does Usage with Callback Interface with SessionMode is Mandatory?

Tags: wcf

I have a service which calls back the client.

the interface has this attribute :

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "rf.services", CallbackContract = typeof (ISendBAck), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

Does the **SessionMode**  field is mandatory ?

why do i need it here ? 
If i remove it  , it still works. but this is a downloaded working example. and i wanted to know why it is there from the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation where oneway oneway operations and callbacks are used, the processing of messages may be queued. The use of sessions is not mandatory but provides assurance that messages will be processed in the order they are received.

This assurances simply has a greater value to the client in scenarios where the call to the service might return before processing is completed.

Comment: ,if i set it to NOtAllowed theres an exception :Contract does not allow Session, but Binding 'NetTcpBinding' does not support Datagram or is not configured properly to support it.

Comment: Yes which it should. TCP is inherently a session oriented protocol. So you can't use it if the contract says sessions aren't permitted.